# ionic-deeplink-plugin not working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I was following the tutorial at http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/ on how to do Deeplinking in Ionic Apps.  I installed the plugin for my app:

cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=urlISet --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=urlISet.com

I then went to test it for Android.  I did 
 'ionic build Android' in terminal, 
and then 
 'ionic emulate Android' in terminal.

Once the emulator came up, I sent the app back to the home page (to make the app not in focus) and then back in terminal within my apps directory I did what the tutorial said to do to test it:

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "urlIset://"

The app becomes the focus once again in the emulator (expected behavior and verification - according to the tutorial that it is configured right for Android).  However, if I then open up chrome in my emulator (or any other browser) and type into the address bar:  "urlIset://" Then it does not load the app.  It does a search for the URL instead - like it can't find it or understand it so it must be a search term.  My understanding of the deeplinking is this should launch the app.

The reason I am doing this is that the logging in method that I have to use through the third party vender for my app requires redirecting the user outside of the app to a specific URL and give them a return URL to send the user to once they are verified. For example, I would send the user to:

https://www.theverificationsite.com/login?returnURL=urlISet://

I am trying to send the "urlIset://" as the return URL so that once they are authenticated by the outside web page, they can be sent back into the app.  It seems as though deeplinking is the best way to achieve this behavior - although I'm up for any other suggestions.  I'm having trouble even finding any other posts about the deeplinking not working so I am stuck.  I'm not even sure what files might be useful to post to help troubleshoot, but if you ask, I can post.  It seems like the fact that the terminal command works while the URL within a browser does not could be a big hint of some easy setting that I am missing?

Here is my android.json file per request:

```
{
"prepare_queue": {
    "installed": [],
    "uninstalled": []
},
"config_munge": {
    "files": {}
},
"installed_plugins": {
    "cordova-plugin-console": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-device": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    },
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    },
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "urlISet",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "urlISet.com",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.deeplinkapp2676485"
    }
},
"dependent_plugins": {}
```

}

One other thing maybe I should mention.  All I did was create a new blank ionic project, and then install the deeplinking.  I wanted to figure out how to get it working before I actually did it to my real app.  So, it is really easy to repeat.  Just create a new blank app (ionic start deeplinkAgain blank), and then install the deeplinking according to the tutorial.  I used 'urlISet' as my 'ionichats'.  Also, im using ionic version 2.1.4.

Comment: Did you follow the step about configuring your webserver for App Links?(https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html). Particularly the part about publishing a Digital Asset Links JSON file on your websites to provide verification?

You didn't mention the steps you took to do that. Can you show us your json file?

Comment: I added the json file above.  Im reading through what you added.  I guess I was mostly thinking that the tutorial was saying 'For Android, it pretty much Just Works from the plugin install above.' was true  - apparently that isn't the case?

Comment: And this is already in my AndroidManifest.xml - Im assuming due to the plugin install:   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="urlISet" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: I take back my last comment. What you have SHOULD work. Can you tell us what version of Android you are running on your emulator?

Comment: My emulator is through Android Virtual Device Manager - its a Android 7.1.1 (Nexus S API 25).  It also doesn't work when I put on my personal phone which is Android 5.0.1.

Comment: It's quite possible that the browser just doesn't support URL scheme in the address bar. Could you try making a simple HTML page with an anchor like so: `<a href="urliset://">Url Scheme Test</a>`. Then click the link and see if that opens your app

Comment: Created a link at http://www.bendbulletin.com/csp/mediapool/sites/shared/assets/csp/utils/playground/deepLinkTest.csp  When I click on it from the emulator while on that page in chrome I can see it loading and then it is on the same page.  No app launch.

Comment: Well, deep links on Android and iOS went through some major changes fairly recently. Event though the URL schema is not working, you can still use the `http://yourwebsite.com` method. But, it will require you to access the web server of that sight. Check out the docs for that plugin on github, and follow the link at the bottom to set it up on your website.